# I am trying to animate and scale image at the same time in jquery but not able to animate the image to the exact top and left positions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to change it's top and left positions but everytime I do it, the image animates and scales to a fixed position rather than the given position.Try changing the top and left of the js and the image doesn't animates elsewhere to the desired position. The css or html might be wrong it seems. Please help me out.

[Here is the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitgada/pxckj6bp/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#logo').animate({
   left: 500,
   top: 100,
  height: "50px",
    width: "100px",
 
}, 2000)
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
  width: 90%;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
  background: rgb(234, 235, 235);
  color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

div, p {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

div {
 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <p>
  Refresh this page to re-run the demo.
</p>

<div>
  <img id="logo" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"/>
  
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Do you also want to change (animate) the size of the image.

Comment: yes I also want to change the size of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `position:relative` to your image style.

```
img {
    position:relative;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxckj6bp/2/)**

As stated [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible
>   effect on elements if their  position style property is static, which
>   it is by default.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in comment, image disappears. This is because the div element contains a `overflow:hidden` property. When image overflows the div where it's contained in, it becomes hidden. You should comment the property to keep image always visible.

```
div {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxckj6bp/4/)

Comment: I did apply position relative but my actual image is different ie its a huge image in png. So when i apply position relative and then give the top and left then the image gets hidden. I need to animate and scale it and not get reduced to invisible. Please suggest.